# Multiple Non-XA Data Source Connections in Single Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, datasource, jta

I have a scenario, Where we need to connect to multiple databases from a single Java application. I understand that i might need to use a XA DataSource, But in my case i have only one primary database where i need to do read / write. In other databases, I need to do only limited read operation.

Is it possible to use multiple Non-XA DB Connections in this case?

Comment: It is definately possible to use multiple NON-XA connections in your case.

Comment: Can you give me some more details on how this can be achieved? a link or blog post would really help.